# Start another EXE in Managed Code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

Is it possible to start another EXE in Managed Code?  At this time, all I can do is use:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(exeName)
```

Is there another way to call another EXE within the same project?

Thanks!
JFV

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\test.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/e /s";
            process.Start();
```

This way you get a lot of options for your process such as process.WaitForExit() so you may not run asynchronously your process, etc.

Comment: I use this method for a few testing projects we have set up.

Answer (score 4):

You could use Assembly.ExecuteAssembly if it is managed. This will execute the main entry point in your current process instead of spinning up a new process.

Answer (score 1):

Use relative paths and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths use the CurrentDirectory, a user can easily change this when launching your app and it can change during execution. I'd recommend using something you can be certain about:

There's a lot of different ways to get your executable's path:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory

Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```