# If checkbox is checked, run "something"

Tags: vb.net

I've got a simple Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition form which looks like this:
[link Screenshot of simple form][1]

I need some help with a skeleton script, which checks to see if each checkbox is checked or not. 
I've got a  set of Word templates which all contain a macro.
And I want to run the macro of each template, *if* the template exists.

So basically something like the following (including loads of errors, probably):

```
    Dim strFile1
    Dim strFile2
    Dim strFile3
    Dim strFile4
    Dim strFile5
    Dim strFile6

if checkbox1.Checked Then
try to run command (Winword.exe c:\temp\document.doc /mNameOfMacro)
On error MsgBox ("could not find file from checkbox1")

    if checkbox2.Checked Then
try to run command (Winword.exe c:\temp\document2.doc /mNameOfMacro)
On error MsgBox ("could not find file from checkbox2")

    if checkbox3.Checked Then
try to run command (Winword.exe c:\temp\document3.doc /mNameOfMacro)
On error MsgBox ("could not find file from checkbox3")

    if checkbox4.Checked Then
try to run command (Winword.exe c:\temp\document4.doc /mNameOfMacro)
On error MsgBox ("could not find file from checkbox4")


    if checkbox5.Checked Then
try to run command (Winword.exe c:\temp\document5.doc /mNameOfMacro)
On error MsgBox ("could not find file from checkbox5")

    if checkbox5.Checked Then
try to run command (Winword.exe c:\temp\document5.doc /mNameOfMacro)
On error MsgBox ("could not find file from checkbox5")
```

I know this pseudocode isn't correct at all, because I'm kind of a beginner, and designer over a programmer. But I've just started learning and I know this is pretty basic. 
It's just getting an overview of the logics in programming. And I think that getting to learn how to do this will help me with other things as well.

Comment: Check this link to a SO question that I asked recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737444/start-another-exe-in-managed-code JFV

Comment: Are you looking for sample code that does what your pseudo-code does? Let me know so I can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, just found the answer by doing this:

```
 Dim strFile1 = ("c:\temp\file3.txt")
 Dim strFile2 = ("c:\temp\file4.txt")

    If chkbxRapport.Checked Then
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(strFile1) Then
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(strFile1)
        Else : MsgBox("Can't find the file" & " " & strFile1)
        End If
    End If

    If chkbxRapport_EN.Checked Then
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(strFile2) Then
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(strFile2)
        Else : MsgBox("Can't find the file" & " " & strFile2)
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: Nevertheless that you found the answer to your question I don't think it is a "good idea"(TM) anyway. Users are expecting to (de)select something when they deal with checkboxes; they don't expect that something happens when they check or uncheck them. It would be better to have a separate "apply" button that executes all the checked scripts. Just my 2c :-)

Comment: Yes of course :) This is the code that's executed on a buttons Click event. This doesn't happen as the user check or uncheck the checkboxes :)

Comment: "2c" By: Lothar:

How do we write the cent symbol on our keyboards? Hmmm...? lol

Answer (score 0):

This blog post should explain it sufficiently.
[Running a process in VB](http://blogs.msdn.com/vbfaq/archive/2004/05/30/144573.aspx)

Its [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) that you are most interested in.

Comment: Thanx, I've got that part. 
But what about the checkboxes? Got any examples?

Comment: Your pseudocode for checking if a checkbox is checked is basically valid.  I am not sure what it is you need?  I assume you have some kind of button or action that starts this process off, like a button OnClick even handler, in which you would implement your tests if checkboxs are checked or not.  What part is it you are having trouble with, as I am not really sure what I would be giving you an example of?