# how to read check box in a word document in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

hi friends present i am working as developes,
i want code for the following scenario
my scenario is the word document must contain checkbox, and this word document should read to asp.net page, when user click the check box, the selected value should be stored into the database

can any one help me

Comment: you mean to say:
there is a word document which contains checkboxes in addition to other entries
user uploads a word document using asp.net
asp.net needs to check if the checkbox is checked and based on that do some action

is this what you want?

Comment: pls check this question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864767/if-checkbox-is-checked-run-something

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, what you're trying to do is to read a column inside a word document, and store the values into a database.

**First approach - sharepoint**

It seems to be a perfect fit for sharepoint. If that is an option you can do the following:

1. set up sharepoint
2. set up a document library
3. [set up a document template](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/HA011612281033.aspx)

The user will have a form to fill values into, but also available in a word document format.

This technique may be overkill depending on what you ultimately want to do.

**Second approach - Office SDK**

Microsoft Office SDK comes with the [CheckBox object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb257481.aspx). You can try open up the document programmatically and interogate the CheckBox object.

I would not advice this code to be run on the server as Microsoft Office isn't meant to be run as a server. Whereas Sharepoint is.

If you really want to do this, you may need to write a queueing mechanism so that the act of running the office sdk calls is batched and run one at a time in sequence.